# Making a phone or email input required after user selects radio button

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, fieldset

I have two radio buttons. One for phone and one for email. Whichever button a user selects that field changes to required and the user has to fill it in. Can someone help me create this through Javascript?  I would appreciate!!

This is my HTML

```
            <input type="radio" id="phone" name="phone">
            <input type="radio" id="email" name="email">
```

Comment: The radio buttons should have the same `name`, otherwise they are both just a single choice in a group. The `value` could be "phone" and "email".

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Fixed the name, thank you for that. This is what I have tried .  if (document.getElementById("emailbtn").checked == true) {
    alert("Please input email");
    return false;
  }

Answer (score 0):

On StackOverflow we love to help fellow developers out, but not to "do work" for free. Instead of writing the code, I'd love to point you towards the right direction.

**You are probably looking for:**

- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- with the according [event type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), which should be [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) in your case (see the "Examples" section on the linked documentation).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using javascript and css properties, please follow below code snippet:

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('noCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
    }

}
```

```html
Yes <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck">
No <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck">
<br>
    <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
        <input placeholder='phone' type='text' id='phone' name='phone'>
    </div>
    <div id="ifNo" style="display:none">
        <input placeholder='email' type='text' id='email' name='email'>
    </div>
```